# Get the index of the max value using argmax in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

1. I have allocated about 34G of memory and read the data in: sst = np.empty([365,3600,7200], dtype-np.float32)
2. using the argmax(sst,axis=0) to get the index of the max value for each pixel.
3. the memory error problem appeared when running the program.

Can anyone help me with this? Are there any other ways to get the index of the max value for each pixel [365,3600,7200]? Thank you!

Comment: I think your error comes from your attempt to allocate such a huge array. I don't think your system has enough memory for such an operation.

Comment: I got 64G of memory in total. I have tried to keep the first step to allocate [365,3600,7200]. When it comes to the second step, I tried the index of the max values for each pixel of half year argmax(sst[:183],axis=0). The program works this time. But I want to get the index of each pixel for the whole year. :(

Comment: I need to keep the origin index cause i need to know for each pixel which day the max value come from. Can you help me?

Comment: Usually, people try to limit the usage of the memory. This is useful when you move your code to another limited-memory computer. I think, it's better to loop over the days, each get the index of max value in each day's photo. Store the max and its location in a list. By the end, you have a list of 356 elements, each of the form (index, max). This can easily be searched for the max of the max.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

[This source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.11.0/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py#L917-L974) shows that argMax returns an array populated by the max on that axis. Instead of doing this, you could say allocate a new array for each axis, and do np.argMax on that array. If you make sure to overwrite the old array after getting the index of that max value you should have less memory issues.

If you're doing a lot of stuff dealing with out-of-memory problems, it may be worth looking into [dask](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/array.html).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: I followed the same logic and did np.argMax to the west world[365,3600,3600] and then the east world[365,3600,3600:7200].